# Splitting a String at last occurrence of slash

Tags: java, string, split

In java I can split at the last occurrence of a character (dot in this case) like this: `String[] parts2 = path.split("\\.(?=[^.]*$)");      String Folderpath = parts2[0];` But when I try to split it at the last occurrence of a slash, like this: `String[] parts2 = path.split("\\/(?=[^.]*$)"); String Folderpath = parts2[0];` it gives me following Warning: [Redundant character escape '\/' in RegExp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TuxB.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe `"/(?=[^/]*$)"`, despite `lastIndexOf` is much more *natural*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job.

```
String folderPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

But your actual problem is that '/' is not special in Java regular expression syntax and therefore does not need to be escaped with '\'.  That's what the warning message is telling you. Delete the backslash that precedes '/'.

Comment: don't forget to test if the index returned by `lastIndexOf`  is not `-1`

Comment: Nah, just write the exception handler :-)   You are of course correct, but my point was to demonstrate technique, not write production code.

Comment: Thanks!
Greetings Alexander